# Merge data into two destination tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, merge

I need to merge data from a donor table into two destination tables. The structure is as below. If a projid is not found in the trace table, i need to create new component in the component table and use the new id to insert into the trace table. Also, for those items that no longer exist in the donor table, the trace table 'active' column should be marked 0. Can i achieve this in a single merge statement?

**Donor Table**

```
projid      | datestamp    | Ownerid
-------------------------------------------------
c_abc        1-jan-2013      name1
c_def        2-jan-2013      name3
c_ghi        3-jan-2013      name4
```

**trace table**

```
compid      |projid     |active | ... 
-----------------------------------------------
123           c_abc      1
124           c_xyz      1
125           c_def      1
```

**component table**

```
compid      |ownerid
-------------------------
123      name1
124      name2
125      name3
```

*OUTPUT TABLES AFTER MERGE:*

**component table**

```
compid      |ownerid
-------------------------
123      name1
124      name2
125      name3
126      name4
```

**trace table**

```
compid      |projid     |active | ... 
-----------------------------------------------
123          c_abc       1
124          c_xyz       0
125          c_def       1
126          c_ghi       1
```

Comment: Where did that `name4` came from?

Comment: name4 comes from the donor table as well

Comment: @mhn - are you saying that there's another column in the Donor table that contains that text? If so, can you add it to your example?

Comment: yes there is.. editted now..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Theoretically, there should be a solution to do this in single statement, but I have so far failed to find it. *

Here is how it can be done with two `MERGE` statements:

```
WITH CTE_trgt AS 
(
    SELECT c.compid, c.ownerid, t.projid, t.active 
    FROM component c
    INNER JOIN trace t ON c.compid = t.compid
)
MERGE CTE_trgt t
USING Donor s
ON t.projid = s.projid
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
    THEN INSERT (ownerid)
    VALUES (s.ownerid)
OUTPUT
    INSERTED.compid, s.projid, 1 INTO trace;


MERGE trace t
USING Donor s
ON t.projid = s.projid
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE 
    THEN UPDATE SET t.active = 0;
```

**[SQLFiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9ca669/6)**

---

*
Part with updating Active column:

```
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE 
    THEN UPDATE SET t.active = 0
```

should be able to fit in the upper query creating a [single merge statement](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9ca669/8) for all operations, but it throws an error:

> View or function 't' is not updatable because the modification affects multiple base tables

even if it's obviously single column, and [regular non-merge update works fine](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9ca669/7). Maybe someone knows a reason and/or a workaround for this.

Comment: Hi Nenad, thanks a lot for your inputs!! the first merge statement went fine. But the statement which updates active flag in trace table i'm not able to customize the way i want. I missed another column donorid in trace. So i need to update only those rows where donorid = 'MyDonorId'. I am not able to accomodate this where clause  anywhere on the merge statement. i tried

Comment: ...MERGE (select * from trace where donorid = 'MyDonorId'  )t
USING Donor s
ON t.projid = s.projid
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE 
    THEN UPDATE SET t.active = 0;  It says bad syntax :(

Comment: @mhn You can use common table expression - `WITH CTE` syntax, like in the first statement to filter your target

Comment: `WITH CTE_Trace as (select * from trace where donorid = 'MyDonorId' ) MERGE CTE_Trace t USING Donor... `