# SQL server merge statement with two tables as Target

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge

Is it possible to use two tables as target in SQL merge statement?
Currently i'm using structure:

```
    MERGE table_name1 as Target
    USING 
------
```

But i need to work with 2 tables at time:

something like:

```
  MERGE table_name1, table_name2 as Target
    USING
```

Current structure (i can't discribe table 2 as target):

```
MERGE table1 as Target

USING 
(
DATASOURCE
) 
as Source

ON 
              Target.id = Source.id

WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN

INSERT VALUES INTO TABLE1
THEN  GET ID FROM TABLE1
INSERT VALUES, ID INTO TABLE 2



WHEN MATCHED AND EXISTS
(

SELECT 


SOURCE.column

EXCEPT

SELECT

Target.column
)
THEN 
UPDATE
    SET
Target.name1 = Source.name1
;
```

Comment: No. It's not supported

Comment: Maybe you want to explain what you are really trying to do... Sound like the [XY-Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: There isn't a way, and there shouldn't be a way. This will be messy and harder to do any maintenance on.

Comment: @Shnugo I have two joined tables and i need to update first then insert id from first and update second. Or insert in to first then take id from first insert into first and insert date into first as well

Comment: Please provide some sample data, edit your question and add a minimal scenario (`CREATE TABLE #tbl1( ...` and some `INSERT INTO #tbl1 ...` and your expected output

Comment: This would be like allowing 2 tables in an insert statement. It just doesn't make sense.

Comment: @SeanLange you exactly right

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merge data into two destination tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18142539/merge-data-into-two-destination-tables)

Comment: The solution is to use multiple merge statemens in succession. Be careful with deletes when there are foreign key references.