# SQL Merge Statement with Intersection table

Tags: sql, intersection

See also:
- [SQL server merge statement with two tables as Target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36033803/sql-server-merge-statement-with-two-tables-as-target)

Does the SQL `MERGE` statement support or what is the workaround to deal with Intersection Tables, when the source table has no intersection table design?

An intersection table is a table that sits between 2 tables so that you can have many to many relationships. The intersection table just holds the keys of both (e.g see here: [Many to Many Relation Design - Intersection Table Design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/977615/many-to-many-relation-design-intersection-table-design))

In my case the source table looks like

- a primary key A
- a comment field 1
- a comment field 2
- a comment field 3

The target table(s) are a table that holds:

- a primary key B (unique, specific for this table)
- a comment

and an intersection table that holds

- the primary key A (the same as the source table)
- the primary key B (the one from the target table)

I want to merge from and to so both sides with 2 merge statements.

Comment: What do you mean by "merge from and to both sides"? What is the intended role of the intersection table? (Why do you need many-to-many relations between A and B for your "merge" logic?) Can you provide some small example table populations and explain more accurately what you expect to happen with that example data during your "merges"? What DBMS are you using?

Comment: Without example data: does the SQL (transact-SQL) support intersection tables. This is a generic question like "do birds fly". Or do you mean: why would someone EVER need to use intersection tables?

Comment: As far as I know, an "intersection table" (for "associative entities") is just what it is: a table, nothing more. It contains fields that can hold the keys for the foreign key relations to two (or more?) other (entity) tables to establish a (often many-to-many) relation. I think that every relational database is capable of creating such a table. So yes, it is supported in SQL Server too. It's just a plain CREATE TABLE statement. But I assume this is not what you mean, so I probably do not understand your question and/or the issue at hand.

Comment: A MERGE-statement, on the other hand, has nothing directly to do with intersection tables and/or many-to-many relations. It's just an SQL statement that can perform an insert, an update and/or a delete action in one single command.

Comment: All this is very nice, but at the end, I still fail to understand why. Why do you want to use an intersection table to establish a many-to-many relationship between A and B? And what do you want to accomplish with your "merges"? If I know what kind if data you have (sample data) and what you want to achieve (expected result), I may be able to help you more effectively.